# How to assign an object to a property of an object in a vector with raw pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, raw-pointer

This question is probably going to be a noob question because I have just started out with C++. But I cannot find out what I am doing wrong. The project that I am working on is an assignment for school. In this assignment, we are only allowed to use raw pointers, so we find out how raw pointers work.

Now those raw pointers gave me some trouble. Those pointers gave me the error: 'no suitable conversion function from "Room" to "Room *" exists'.

To try and explain how I caused this error I will try to give a stripped-down version of the code that I have written.

```
class Level
{
private:
    Room _startRoom;
    vector<vector<Room>> _rooms;
};

class Room
{
public:
    Room *North;
    Room *East;
    Room *South;
    Room *West;
};
```

I have a class named Level this is a class with a vector in a vector to be able to print out the Rooms next to each other neatly. Not every room is connected, so I gave the Room direction-properties for the connections with the other rooms. But when I try to generate the connections between the rooms, by setting _rooms[y][x].South with _rooms[y+1][x]. I got the error: 'no suitable conversion function from "Room" to "Room *" exists'.

Could someone clarify why I am getting this error message? All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `_rooms[y + 1][x]` is a `Room` instance, not a pointer to a room. To get a pointer to it you need to use the address-of operator `&`:

```
_rooms[y][x].South = &_rooms[y+1][x];
```

On an unrelated note: You do remember to populate the vectors in your `Level` object?

Comment: Yea, I have initialized them but because I tried to keep te code as much as possible focussed on the problem. Therefore I left that part out :p. And thank you, placing an ampersand before it the variable worked. But why can you only place a reference into a pointer?